# Rails 4.2.0 beta4 - Haml with no output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed haml gem in my rails app (v4.2.0 beta4)
but it doesn't seem to compile any output.

I have included gem in my `gemfile` and ran `bundle install` and made sure
that I changed my `html.erb` files to `html.haml`

This is one of the template and all I see is the heading `"New recipe"`.

```
%h1 New recipe
= render 'form'
= link_to 'Back', recipes_path
```

And nothing gets displayed for form partial.

I've come across someone with similar issue and the solution to the issue was making controller inherit
`applicationController` rather than `actionController`.

I wonder if this is what I need to do to make it working.
I would have thought installing haml gem would have handled everything needed to get it working.

Comment: Yes. They are all in the same folder and all are .html.haml

Comment: I don't see back link either so it doesn't look like an issue with the form itself as simple like `= link_to 'Back', recipes_path` doesn't show. All I see is the static h1 heading.

Comment: I got it from https://rubygems.org/gems/haml

Comment: You didn't install it through bundler?  What specifically is in your gemfile? Do you have `gem 'haml-rails'`?

Comment: I ended up installing it through bundler but I initially ran with `gem install haml` by mistake and not sure if this could be the cause. I did uninstall/install a couple times with bundler after that.

Comment: Do you have `gem 'haml-rails'` in your Gemfile?

Comment: No I don't. Do I need that gem as well? I didn't know it was requirement for Rails 4

Comment: It's not only a requirement for rails 4, it's a requirement for ruby on rails, it provides the wrappers needed to integrate rails logic in your Haml views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downgrading my project to 4.1.8 and Haml works just fine.
gem 'haml-rails' was not necessary. 
gem 'haml' did the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Gemfile`, put

```
gem "haml-rails"
```

And then of course `bundle install`

This is the ONLY gem you need to integrate HAML into your Rails app, as it provides the wrappers needed to be able to use ruby logic in your haml views.  Simply using haml alone is not sufficient as haml is framework independent.

Comment: @SeongLee, is your project on a github or public repo?  Unless I see the whole picture I can't really figure this out.

Comment: I've created a new project with Rails 4.1.8 and copied over the same form partial and everything from the 4.2.0 beta4 project and haml now works here. Weird

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it's a bug with the beta version of Rails.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm inclined to mark your answer as chosen but it may violate the rule here and confuse other people as the final solution to the issue so I will leave it as is. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I would suggest making a new answer with your conclusions, and then marking that one.  That way the question closes.  And good luck

Answer (score 1):

Since you've added the HAML gem (`gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'`), ran bundle install and restarted your server (Have you restarted your server??) I believe you have installed the Gem correctly.

When you say in your template file you see `"New recipe"`, it makes me think the issue is not with the haml gem but with partial file.

Just to confirm, your partial is saved within the same folder (`app/views/recipes/`) as:

```
_form.html.haml
```

You need to make sure you have the underscore in front of the file name for partials.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I believe I did a good sanity check to make sure they are properly formatted and named. I made a new rails app version 4.1.8 and installed those gems with the same form partial and formatting and it now works on this project. Weird huh..